# Deblurring of motion blurred images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm looking at an interesting problem of deblurring motion blurred images. Rather than going for guesses of psf, I'm interested in finding out the actual blur parameters (angle and length). I was successful in finding angle of blur to a certain extent, and need a good technique for finding blur length. If any one has a good idea or code or reference to suggest, it will be helpful. I'm working with MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

The "actual blur parameters" are just a much higher order approximation to the [point spread function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) than the angle/length, which would just be a simple 2d model of said function.  If you are interested in angle/length, you could estimate the PSF with [blind deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_deconvolution) and try to recover angle/length by modeling the PSF as a 2d [Multivariate Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).