# how to deblur the blured image produced due to motion of camera (i.e image with unknown PSF value) in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, motion-blur

i am doing my project in image processing and my topic is to deblur the images which are blurred due to camera motion. so how can i deblur that image without knowing its PSF value.
is there any predefined method or any code available in matlab ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786483/deblurring-of-motion-blurred-images?rq=1

Comment: thanks but i didn't get info any from it... i didnt find it much useful for me. if have any idea or know any algorithm please provide me